# What does net::high_resolution_timer(co_await net::this_coro::executor) do?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, c++20, c++-coroutine

I was reading the blog about boost asio, ([source code](https://github.com/madmongo1/blog-october-2020/blob/stage-1/src/test_widget.cpp))
and noticed the following code.

```
auto timer = net::high_resolution_timer(co_await net::this_coro::executor);
```

It is not clear to me why timer is constructed using `co_await` in argument since most of the time I saw `co_await` used before some called function, not when providing an argument to constructor.

I have checked the boost docs, but there seems to be nothing too notable about timer [constuctors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/basic_waitable_timer.html), they take executor as argument, but still not clear to me why co_await is needed.

Full function code is this:

```
net::awaitable<void>
test_widget::run_demo()
{
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto timer = net::high_resolution_timer(co_await net::this_coro::executor);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        timer.expires_after(1s);
        co_await timer.async_wait(net::use_awaitable);
        this->setText(QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(i + 1) + " seconds"));
    }
    co_return;
}
```

Comment: [`net::this_core::executor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/this_coro__executor.html) is an awaitable object, hence the `co_await`.

Comment: this may be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65821773/what-is-the-implement-of-asiothis-coroexecutor