# What is the implement of asio::this_coro::executor

Tags: c++, boost, asio

In a coroutine function, we can add `auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;` to get the executor of this coroutine. But when I want to learn the definition of it, I found this:

```cpp
/// Awaitable type that returns the executor of the current coroutine.
struct executor_t
{
  ASIO_CONSTEXPR executor_t()// ASIO_CONSTEXPR is defined constexpr
  {
  }
};

/// Awaitable object that returns the executor of the current coroutine.
#if defined(ASIO_HAS_CONSTEXPR) || defined(GENERATING_DOCUMENTATION)
constexpr executor_t executor;
#elif defined(ASIO_MSVC)
__declspec(selectany) executor_t executor;
#endif
```

Why does executor awiatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), when `co_await` is reached, the expression following the `co_await` is converted to an awaitable:

> otherwise, if the current coroutine's Promise type has the member function await_transform, then the awaitable is promise.await_transform(expr)

Looking at the `coro_promise` type defined in [asio/include/asio/experimental/coro.hpp](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/experimental/coro.hpp) we can indeed find an overload of this method taking `this_coro::executor_t` as parameter:

```
  auto await_transform(this_coro::executor_t) const
  {
    struct exec_helper
    {
      const executor_type& value;

      constexpr static bool await_ready() noexcept { return true; }

      constexpr static void await_suspend(coroutine_handle<>) noexcept {}

      executor_type await_resume() const noexcept { return value; }
    };

    return exec_helper{executor_};
  }
```

This won't suspend the coroutine since `await_ready()` of `exec_helper` always returns `true`. Instead it will immediately call `await_resume()` which, as you can see above, returns the executor stored in the current promise.

So the only purpose of the `this_coro::executor_t` is for overload resolution. There is another overload for `this_coro::cancellation_state_t` which has a similar empty definition that serves the same purpose.

The global variable `constexpr executor_t executor;` is there so that you can pass `this_coro::executor` instead of `this_coro::executor_t{}` to the `co_await` operator inside your coroutine.